# Is asyncio's loop.run_in_executor thread-safe?

Tags: python, thread-safety, python-asyncio

I'm trying out asyncio and have to mix it with some normal multi threaded blocking code, so I need to offload the execution using run_in_exector.

The [asyncio docs warn that "most functions" aren't threadsafe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading), and that `call_soon_threadsafe` is the only thread-safe function. There are a couple others, like `Future.add_done_callback`, too, that are explicitly documented as thread safe. It then has a sentence afterwards saying "you can use run_in_executor to run callbacks in other threads", but doesn't comment on the thread-safety of it specifically.

[run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor) isn't doc'd to be thread-safe, but looking at the source, it looks like it is thread safe if the right code-paths are taken.

Does anyone know if it is *supposed* to be thread safe, but just isn't documented to be that way?

Comment: What do you mean by "thread-safe" in this context? The documentation uses that term to indicate if it's safe to call a given method from a thread outside of the one running the `asyncio` event loop. That's probably not what you're asking here, though, is it?

Comment: That's exactly what i meant. I have some existing multi threaded code and am trying to use asyncio with it, so i need a thread safe way to schedule blocking code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`run_in_executor` is supposed to be *not threadsafe* by *specification* (sorry, it looks like implicit statement and probably should be clarified in PEP-3156).

Even if concrete implementation is thread safe please don't assume that any PEP-3156 compliant implementation will be thread-safe too.

Comment: The correct way to make it (or anything) thread thread safe is to wrap it in call_soon_threadsafe:

`loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.run_in_executor, executor, callback, *args))`

Answer (score 3):

I think it entirely depends on what you give it. It effectively just starts a thread and runs your code, so whether that is thread safe or not depends on what you tell it to do.

Answer (score 3):

The default implementation looks to be thread-safe if the executor parameter is not None or the default executor is already set (call loop.set_default_executor()). Otherwise, two executor may be created.

You may write a patch to make the method thread-safe ;-)